# Multiple directives error though there is only one added

Tags: angularjs

While creating a directive I am getting following error.

I am getting following error

> 13642 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [myDirective (module: myApp), myDirective (module: myApp)] asking for template on:

I am new to directive creation. Can you explain -

1. Though I use only one directive, it is saying multiple directives. Which are the other directives here?
2. How to resolve this error?

**UPDATE**

After removing the templateUrl, the error is gone. But the value was not rendered. As mentioned in the answer it is because of the creation of `isolated scope` rather than a `shared scope`.

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //defining module
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

        //defining controller
        app.controller('myController', function ($scope) 
 {
            $scope.myVal = 'A';

        });

 app.directive('myDirective', function () 
{
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',      
        scope: {title: '@' },
        template: '<div>{{ myVal }}</div>',
        templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) { } 
    }
});


    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
       <div my-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have a template and a templateUrl? Should only need one or the other.

Comment: Read Error page (everything). It explains *why* in clear English. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=myDirective&p1=%20(module:%20myApp)&p2=myDirective&p3=%20(module:%20myApp)&p4=template&p5=%3Cdiv%20my-directive%3D%22%22%3E

Comment: @dfsq I just read. It doesn't say about one directive with multiple templates causing this problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to define two templates for the same directive (template and templateUrl). Remove one or the other and it will resolve your error

---

Edit:

You are creating an isolate scope when you specify a local scope in your directive. [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope) is a good resource to learn more about directive scopes in angular

Comment: Removed the templateURL and the error is gone. But it is not displaying the value from the controller - `myVal`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

A similar error can occur when you accidentally define two directives/components with the same name. Then Angular will try to apply both on the element, and the error will show the same name, whereas in fact they are different directives.